# Creating a Survival Analysis dataset

Tags: r

I have a table composed by three columns: ID, Opening Date and Cancelation Date.

[image]

What I want to do is to create 36 observations per client (one per month for 3 years) as a dummy variable. Basically, i want all the months observations before the cancelation date to have a 1 and the others a 0. In case that the cancelation date is null, then all of the values would be 1.

This process should be repeated for every ID.

The desired output would be a table with five columns: ID, Opening Date, Cancelation Date, Month (from 1 to 36, starting on opening date) and Status (1 or 0).

[image]

I've tried everything but havent managed to solve this problem, using seq() to create the dates and order them `seq(table$Opening, by = "month", length.out = 36)` and many other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` to create a dates of 1-month sequence for each `ID`, create a `row_number` for each group as count of `Month` and create `Status` based on `Cancellation_Date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Date")), as.Date, "%d/%m/%y") %>%
  mutate(Date = Opening_Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  complete(Date = seq(Date,by = "1 month", length.out = 36)) %>%
  mutate(Month = row_number()) %>%
  fill(Opening_Date, Cancellation_Date) %>%
  mutate(Status = +(Date <= Cancellation_Date))

#      ID Date       Opening_Date Cancellation_Date Month Status
#   <dbl> <date>     <date>       <date>            <int>  <int>
# 1   336 2017-01-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            1      1
# 2   336 2017-02-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            2      1
# 3   336 2017-03-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            3      1
# 4   336 2017-04-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            4      1
# 5   336 2017-05-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            5      1
# 6   336 2017-06-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            6      1
# 7   336 2017-07-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            7      1
# 8   336 2017-08-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            8      1
# 9   336 2017-09-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01            9      1
#10   336 2017-10-01 2017-01-01   2018-06-01           10      1
# … with 26 more rows
```

In the output `Date` column is sequence of monthly  dates for each `ID`, which can be removed from the final output if not needed.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 336, Opening_Date = '1/1/17',Cancellation_Date = '1/6/18')
```

Comment: is there a way to stop the Date variable once it gets to todays date? For example, maybe some opened 3 months ago and it would be unrealistic to allow values in the future, therefore, it would be good to only get 3 months of data for those people.

Comment: @Ivancito yes, change the `complete` line to `complete(Date = seq(Date,Sys.Date(),by = "1 month"))`.

Comment: im getting this error: `Error in seq.Date(Fecha, by = "1 month", length.out = 36) : 
  'from' must be of length 1`

Comment: @Ivancito Do you have multiple rows for each `ID` ? In that case, you can do `complete(Date = seq(min(Date),Sys.Date(),by = "1 month"))`. Although confirm that the code before that and after it still remains the same. We need to change only the `complete` line.

Comment: @Ivancito yes, you can specify `by` with `to` but in that case `length.out` will not make sense. See `seq(1, 10, 2)` or `seq(1, 10, length.out = 5)`

Comment: i have a fourth column with a name on it, it returns NA once i run this code. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask a new question with these details since it is becoming quite difficult to understand and solve it in comments.

Comment: well, thank you anyways. You were extremely helpful. I will do some other workarounds to solve the current problems.